# Why should we use three migration commands to migrate our database succesfully?

Tags: python, django

I was working on models in django and after creating classes for models and when migrating them I was supposed to use three commands for completing migration of models. The commands are :`python manage.py migrate`,`python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`,`python manage.py migrate`
So my question is that why should we use three commands like this ?

Comment: you can almost certainly just use the last 2 ... in fact you could do it with just one command `python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/),

> `migrate`: which is responsible for applying and unapplying migrations.
>
> `makemigrations`: which is responsible for creating new
>   migrations based on the changes you have made to your models.

If you make changes to your model use `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate`.

Incase of [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations) migration just after you create an app you dont need to `python manage.py makemigrations`  but just `python manage.py migrate` works.